# @JoinColumn using column from @ManyToOne entity table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following database scheme (kept only the relevant tables):
[image: database scheme]

I need to map organization_internet_domain_categorized into application_organization, but the column internet_domain_id belongs to the table application.

What I've tried:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "application_organization")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class OrganizationApplication implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "application.internet_domain_id", referencedColumnName = "internet_domain_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private InternetDomainCategory internetDomainCategory;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_application_organization_application"))
    private Application application;

    // kept only the mapping part
}
```

What JPA/Hibernate generates:

```
select
    organizati0_.id as id1_3_0_,
    -- removed all the columns to keep only the relevant parts
from
    application_organization organizati0_
left outer join organization_internet_domain_categorized internetdo1_ on
    organizati0_.application.internet_domain_id = internetdo1_.internet_domain_id
    and organizati0_.organization_id = internetdo1_.organization_id
left outer join internet_domain internetdo2_ on
    internetdo1_.internet_domain_id = internetdo2_.id
left outer join Organization organizati3_ on
    internetdo1_.organization_id = organizati3_.id
where
    organizati0_.id =?
```

organizati0_.application.internet_domain_id is not a valid reference.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Turing85 sorry, I removed the image

Comment: "*organizati0_.application.internet_domain_id is not a valid reference.*" - Why do you think that it is not a valid reference?

Comment: Ah I think I see what you did... `@JoinColumn(name = "application.internet_domain_id" ...)` - I do not think this works. You are skipping a `JOIN`. `application` is another entity, i.e. must be joined.

Comment: @Turing85 I need to use the application table internet_domain_id column in order to join organization_internet_domain_categorized. Looks like JoinColumn only allows me to use application_organization columns.
Even if I join the application table by setting Application fetch to EAGER, It still wont be valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping

```
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "application.internet_domain_id", referencedColumnName = "internet_domain_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private InternetDomainCategory internetDomainCategory;
```

is invalid. You can not refer to other tables in the join columns annotation.

It's also unnecessary to do so, as you can access this `InternetDomainCategory` by using `application.getInternetDomainCategory()`.